# How to set title to sublots from a list in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to set title for subplots from array of data.

What I expect to have is that Title-1, Title-2 ... and so on for (00, 01 , 10 and 11) locations in the figure.

So I did;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

title = [1,2,3,4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 8))  

    for i in range(len(ax)): 
        for j in range(len(ax[i])):

            for k in title:
            #    print (k)
                ax[i,j].set_title('Title-' + str(k))
```

But only getting Title-4. How can I fix this issue ?
Thx

[image]

Comment: @sshashank124 No the link does not answer to my question! I have array of data to feed the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method use `flatten` and `enumerate`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

title = [1,2,3,4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 8))  
flat_ax = ax.flatten()

for n, ax in enumerate(flat_ax):
    ax.set_title(f'Title-{title[n]}')
```

Output:

[image]

Another option is to use `iter` with `flatten`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

title = [1,2,3,4]
ititle = iter(title)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 8))  
flat_ax = ax.flatten()

for ax in flat_ax:
    ax.set_title(f'Title-{next(ititle)}')
```

Also, note I am using f-string which requires python 3.6+

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are doing repeated assignments of title looping from 1 up to 4 for each combination of `i`, `j`. You need to refactor your code in a way it does only one assignment for each `i` and `j`:

```
for i in range(len(ax)):
    for j in range(len(ax[i])):
        ax[i,j].set_title('Title-' + str(1+2*i+j))
```

You might also like to make a dictionary

```
codes = {(0,0):1, (0,1):2, (1,0):3, (1,1):4}
```

and replace last line by

```
ax[i,j].set_title('Title-' + str(codes[i,j]))
```

Comment: Thanks! but What if I have `title = [111,223,1233,423]` type title ? the first solution would not apply! secondly, if I have dozens of titles it becomes a little bit troublesome to create a dictionary for each of them!

Comment: I didn't know there's `flatten` method implemented for this purpose in matplotlib

Comment: @mathfux  `flatten` is a numpy array method,  when you have more than 1 axes defined with `plt.subplots` what is returned is numpy array of axes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `ndindex` to iterate over the N-dimensional index of the array:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 8))
titles = [1,2,3,4]

for idx, t in zip(np.ndindex(ax.shape), titles):
    ax[idx].set_title(f'Title {t}')
```